# Goldbach conjecture: Every integer $n>3$ is halfway between $2$ primes.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, integers, prime-gaps, goldbachs-conjecture

Prove that the following conjecture is equivalent to the **strong Goldbach conjecture**:

> Every integer $n>3$ is halfway between $2$ primes.

I'm able to prove it, but i don't have much experience in writing proofs, witch is why i need help to find a proper way to explain it. I'd like to have a proof that is as "short and sweet" as the conjecture itself. The shorter the better!

**What i have so far:**

If $p$ and $q$ are a Goldbach's partition of an even integer $2n$, then:
$$ 2n=p+q $$
The midpoint between $p$ and $q$ is: 
$$\frac{p+q}{2}=\frac{2n}{2}=n$$

Therefore, if an even integer $2n$ can be written as the sum of $2$ primes, $n$ is halfway between those $2$ primes.

Comment: If an even number $n$ is the sum of two primes $a$ and $b$, where is $n/2$?  And is $n/2$ integer?

Comment: Hard to do this without seeing the proof you already have.

Comment: If you give us the proof that you have, we will see if we can (and need to) improve it. Until then there isn't much we can do to help you.

Comment: yes i'm adding what i have so far! should not be long

Comment: In fact, Goldbach's conjecture is equivalent to: "Every integer n>1 is halfway between 2 primes"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, let's do the equivalence.

Say Goldbach's conjecture is true, and take an integer $n>3$. Then there are primes $p, q$ such that $p+q = 2n$, and therefore $n = \frac{p+q}2$ is the midpoint between $p$ and $q$.

On the other hand, let's say your conjecture is true, and let $2n>6$ be an even number. Then there are primes $p, q$ such that $n$ is the midpoint between $p$ and $q$. In other words, $\frac{p+q}2 = n$, which transforms into $p+q = 2n$, and we have shown that the arbitrary even number $2n$ is the sum of two primes.

Thus either conjecture may be used to prove the other, and they are equivalent.

(I'm assuming that the specifics of whether Goldbach's conjecture starts at $4$ or $6$ or $8$ isn't the important part of the conjecture. If you include those cases, then no, the two aren't *entirely* equivalent.)

Comment: The Goldbach's conjecture starts is not really important for the main objective, but still it is interesting.. who knows, maybe 1 is prime after all, this would bring us to n>1 :)

Comment: What about a case where n is prime, with only 1 Goldbach partition (n,n) ? Wouldn't  it respects Goldbach's conjecture but not mine ?