# Is there a conjecture or result such that if it's proven to be true would automatically prove (the Strong) Goldbach's conjecture?

Tags: prime-numbers, natural-numbers, provability, goldbachs-conjecture

I'm just wondering if there's any existing conjectures or results such that if they're proven to be true, Goldbach's conjecture would also be proven to be true.

**Additional Information:**

I've looked at the other post about equivalents of the strong Goldbach's conjecture here:

[What are some equivalent statements of (strong) Goldbach Conjecture?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1084743/what-are-some-equivalent-statements-of-strong-goldbach-conjecture)

But what I mean here is a conjecture not equivalent to Goldbach's, that if proved would imply Goldbach's conjecture is true.

Comment: Yes. One such conjecture is Goldbach's conjecture.

Comment: Already answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1084743/what-are-some-equivalent-statements-of-strong-goldbach-conjecture)

Comment: I assume you mean the strong version (the weak version is implied by the generalized riemann hypothesis and has been solved in the mean time). I am not aware of a conjecture implying the strong version.

Comment: I've added some additional information in the question for clarification.

Comment: $7$ upvotes for a neither helpful nor funny comment.

Comment: @Peter your last comment isn't helpful nor funny either , so...

Comment: @jjagmath So, pointing out unsuitable comments is not helpful ? But the good news for you : My flag was declined, so the moderators are apparently with you.

Comment: Yes if certain inequalities among modular prime counting functions are true they prove Goldbach...